# how can I retrieve individual values from a multi value key in Swift 4/json dictionary?

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, swift4

There are many many examples of retrieving the value of a key, and I can do that. In this case, the key has multiple values. The key is "mining", followed by 6 values. The same key:value is repeated 30 times, with different values for the keys of course.

What I can't seem to solve is how to return the values. Especially the first one, 1532825277682891390, for example, which appears to be a sub-key with key/value pairs related to that.

```
The todo is: ["mining": {
1532825277682891390 =     {
    command = mining;
    siteid = "Platform Mining";
    ts = 1532825270557;
    user1 = 73276;
    value = 1;
};
1532826406100318457 =     {
    command = mining;
    siteid = "Platform Mining";
    ts = 1532826375712;
    user1 = 73276;
    value = 1;
};
1532827074955562013 =     {
    command = mining;
    siteid = "Platform Mining";
    ts = 1532827066645;
    user1 = 73276;
    value = 1;
};
153282775791322835 =     {
    command = mining;
    siteid = "Platform Mining";
    ts = 1532827753205;
    user1 = 73276;
    value = 1;
};

....
....
....
}
```

I can show the key:value for the "mining" key. There are only two keys in the dictionary, 'mining' and 'success' - I'm not worried about 'success', it usually returns '1'.

This is basically the code with a few examples and trial outputs, as I try out different things from other posts. I just can't get my head around this bit.
Do I need to put the dictionary into an array, and how do I do that, or can I just put each value into a var, so I can print them to a UITabDisplay?

```
    func makeGetCall() {
    // Set up the URL request
    let todoEndpoint: String = "https://api.jsecoin.com/v1.7/mining/auth/"

    let apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


    guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    urlRequest.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
            print(error!)
            return
        }


        // make sure we got data
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        print("Got data: \(responseData)")
        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
        do {
            guard let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
                as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    return
            }
            // now we have the todo
            // let's just print it to prove we can access it
           print("The todo is: " + todo.description)

           // from this point on I"m experimenting ....

            let dict = todo.description
            print("The dict is: " + dict)

            let keys = Array(todo.keys)
            // prints ["mining", "success"]
            print(keys)
            /////////////////////////////////
            if let alb = todo["mining"] {
                // prints all the values for 'mining'.
               //  {
               //   1532825277682891390 =     {
               //   command = mining;
               //   siteid = "Platform Mining";
               //   ts = 1532825270557;
              //    user1 = 73276;
              //    value = 1;
             //    };
             // ........ 30 entires
                print(alb)
            }
            //======================
            let index1 = todo.index(forKey: "mining")
            let myMining = (todo[index1!].value)

            // again prints all the mining values. Mining: {
            // 1532825277682891390 =     {
            // command = mining;
            // siteid = "Platform Mining";
            // ts = 1532825270557;
            // user1 = 73276;
            // value = 1;
            // };

            print("Mining: \(myMining)")

            //============
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a similar way you have written for taking the keys of todo dictionary.

```
if let mining = todo["mining"] as? [String: Any] {
   let miningKeys = Array(mining.keys)
   // It will be like [1532825277682891390, 1532826406100318457]
}
```

Use the `miningKeys` for accessing the values from that mining dictionary, like:

```
mining[miningKeys.first!]
// It will return
// {
//   command = mining;
//   siteid = "Platform Mining";
//   ts = 1532825270557;
//   user1 = 73276;
//   value = 1;
// }
```

Comment: this one returns this.
Optional({
    command = mining;
    siteid = "Platform Mining";
    ts = 1532866600000;
    user1 = 73276;
    value = 1;
})
 So my big question now is, how do I I extract each value from each of those sub keys.. my var  'command' = 'mining'?

Comment: This has helped me a lot as well to understand how this works. I understand from the other answer that I should be looking at Codable. I’ll get onto it.

Comment: @HarryMcGovern Thanks for your comment. Yes, you should use Codable and define a model class for storing/using the data.

Answer (score 1):

The value for key `mining` is a dictionary. Conditional downcast `alb` to the expected type and enumerate the dictionary

```
if let alb = todo["mining"] as? [String:Any] {
    for (key, value) in alb {
        print(key, value)
    }
}
```

If you want to print each key-value pair of the inner dictionary separately you could use

```
if let alb = todo["mining"] as? [String:Any] {
    for (key, mining) in alb {
        print(key)
        if let item = mining as? [String:Any] {
           for (key, value) in item {
               print(key, value)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Consider that the `key`s in the `for` loop are not guaranteed to be in the same order as in the JSON.

Comment: so this one returns
1532866606309208293 {
    command = mining;
    siteid = "Platform Mining";
    ts = 1532866600000;
    user1 = 73276;
    value = 1;
}

Comment: What do you expect? The code is supposed to print each key-value pair.

Comment: Thanks, yes, but what I'm trying to do is print, or store in a var, the value for the key mining, like  1532866606309208293, and then the sub keys like
key: command value: mining
key: siteid value: "Platform Mining"
key: ts value: 1532866600000
so I can reference tose individual sub keys.

Comment: ok, now I'm understanding better. Although for some strange reason it's not printing the results in the same order, it is printing them. Now to put those results into variables. Perhaps in an array. Example output from your update.
1532858686602513919
siteid Platform Mining
user1 73276
value 1
command mining
ts 1532858680593

Example normal order.
    1532858686602513919 =     {
        command = mining;
        siteid = "Platform Mining";
        ts = 1532858680593;
        user1 = 73276;
        value = 1;

Comment: Please read the last sentence in my answer. A dictionary is unordered by definition. I recommend to parse the JSON into structs with the `Codable` protocol.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok I’ll try it. Thanks for your help. It’s certainly helped me to understand how this works. So the code you have helped me with can be made to work similarly with the Codable exercise.

Comment: Basically yes, the `Codable` way is more convenient